# Keras custom layer to Conv2D input channels error, ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 50 != 3200

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to create a model with Normalized cross correlation custom layer, code taken from [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/keras-implementation-of-siamese-like-networks.html)

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Flatten
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.engine import InputSpec, Layer
from keras import regularizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.utils.conv_utils import conv_output_length
from keras import activations
import numpy as np


class Normalized_Correlation_Layer(Layer):

# create a class inherited from keras.engine.Layer.

    def __init__(self, patch_size=(5, 5),
          dim_ordering='tf',
          border_mode='same',
          stride=(1, 1),
          activation=None,
          **kwargs):

       if border_mode != 'same': 
          raise ValueError('Invalid border mode for Correlation Layer ' 
                     '(only "same" is supported as of now):', border_mode) 
       self.kernel_size = patch_size 
       self.subsample = stride 
       self.dim_ordering = dim_ordering 
       self.border_mode = border_mode 
       self.activation = activations.get(activation) 
       super(Normalized_Correlation_Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return(input_shape[0][0], input_shape[0][1], input_shape[0][2], self.kernel_size[0] * input_shape[0][2]*input_shape[0][-1])

    def get_config(self): 
        config = {'patch_size': self.kernel_size, 
              'activation': self.activation.__name__, 
              'border_mode': self.border_mode, 
              'stride': self.subsample, 
              'dim_ordering': self.dim_ordering} 
        base_config = super(Correlation_Layer, self).get_config() 
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        input_1, input_2 = x
        stride_row, stride_col = self.subsample
        inp_shape = input_1._keras_shape
        output_shape = self.compute_output_shape([inp_shape, inp_shape])
        padding_row = (int(self.kernel_size[0] / 2),int(self.kernel_size[0] / 2)) 
        padding_col = (int(self.kernel_size[1] / 2),int(self.kernel_size[1] / 2)) 
        input_1 = K.spatial_2d_padding(input_1, padding =(padding_row,padding_col)) 
        input_2 = K.spatial_2d_padding(input_2, padding = ((padding_row[0]*2, padding_row[1]*2),padding_col)) 
        output_row = output_shape[1] 
        output_col = output_shape[2] 
        output = [] 
        for k in range(inp_shape[-1]):
               xc_1 = [] 
               xc_2 = [] 
            #    print("here")
               for i in range(padding_row[0]): 
                  for j in range(output_col): 
                     xc_2.append(K.reshape(input_2[:, i:i+self.kernel_size[0], j:j+self.kernel_size[1], k], 
                                 (-1, 1,self.kernel_size[0]*self.kernel_size[1])))

        for i in range(output_row): 
            slice_row = slice(i, i + self.kernel_size[0]) 
            slice_row2 = slice(i + padding_row[0], i +self.kernel_size[0] + padding_row[0]) 
            # print("dfg")
            for j in range(output_col): 
                slice_col = slice(j, j + self.kernel_size[1]) 
                xc_2.append(K.reshape(input_2[:, slice_row2, slice_col, k], 
                           (-1, 1,self.kernel_size[0]*self.kernel_size[1]))) 
                xc_1.append(K.reshape(input_1[:, slice_row, slice_col, k], 
                             (-1, 1,self.kernel_size[0]*self.kernel_size[1])))
        for i in range(output_row, output_row+padding_row[1]): 
            for j in range(output_col): 
                xc_2.append(K.reshape(input_2[:, i:i+ self.kernel_size[0], j:j+self.kernel_size[1], k], 
                           (-1, 1,self.kernel_size[0]*self.kernel_size[1]))) 

        xc_1_aggregate = K.concatenate(xc_1, axis=1)
        xc_1_mean = K.mean(xc_1_aggregate, axis=-1, keepdims=True) 
        xc_1_std = K.std(xc_1_aggregate, axis=-1, keepdims=True) 
        xc_1_aggregate = (xc_1_aggregate - xc_1_mean) / xc_1_std

        xc_2_aggregate = K.concatenate(xc_2, axis=1)
        xc_2_mean = K.mean(xc_2_aggregate, axis=-1, keepdims=True) 
        xc_2_std = K.std(xc_2_aggregate, axis=-1, keepdims=True) 
        xc_2_aggregate = (xc_2_aggregate - xc_2_mean) / xc_2_std

        xc_1_aggregate = K.permute_dimensions(xc_1_aggregate, (0, 2, 1)) 
        block = [] 
        len_xc_1= len(xc_1) 
        print("asdf")
        for i in range(len_xc_1):
                 #This for loop is to compute the product of a given patch of feature map 1 and the feature maps on which it is supposed to
            sl1 = slice(int(i/inp_shape[2])*inp_shape[2], 
                  int(i/inp_shape[2])*inp_shape[2]+inp_shape[2]*self.kernel_size[0]) 
                      #This calculates which are the patches of feature map 2 to be considered for a given patch of first feature map.

            block.append(K.reshape(K.batch_dot(xc_2_aggregate[:,sl1,:], 
                          xc_1_aggregate[:,:,i]),(-1,1,1,inp_shape[2] *self.kernel_size[0]))) 

        block = K.concatenate(block, axis=1) 
        # print("zxcv")
        block= K.reshape(block,(-1,output_row,output_col,inp_shape[2] *self.kernel_size[0])) 
        output.append(block)

        output = self.activation(output) 

        print(output)
        return output
```

My model is a combination of cross correlation and Conv2D layers,

```
dt = 'float32'
def create_model():
    ip = keras.layers.Input((50,50, 1))
    ncx1_1 =  Normalized_Correlation_Layer(patch_size=(1, 1))([ip,ip])
    ncn1_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation = 'relu', dtype=dt)(ip)
    ncn2_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation = 'relu', dtype=dt)(ncx1_1)
    ncx2_1 =  Normalized_Correlation_Layer(patch_size=(1, 1),dtype=dt)([ncn1_1,ncn2_1])

    # ncx2_1 = keras.layers.Reshape((50, 50, 3200))(ncx2_1)
    # Problem occurs here
    ncn3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(1,1), activation = 'relu', dtype=dt)(ncx2_1)
    ncn4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(12, (1,1), activation = 'sigmoid', dtype=dt)(ncn3)

    model = keras.models.Model(ip,ncn4)

    return model
```

The model till the last cross correlation layer is successfully created, but I get problem for ncn3 layer

```
ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 50 != 3200
```

The output shape printed from the `ncx2_1` layer, while creating it is printed as `(?, 50, 50, 50)`,
when I print `ncx2_1.shape` and also the outputs returned from `call` function of layer class (`[<tf.Tensor 'normalized__correlation__layer_4/Reshape_10000:0' shape=(?, 50, 50, 50) dtype=float32>]`).
But the model summary shows it as `(?,50,50,3200)` when I create the model till that layer only, ie. `model = keras.models.Model(ip,ncx2_1)`

When I reshape the layer using `ncx2_1 = keras.layers.Reshape((50, 50, 3200))(ncx2_1)` , I can create the model successfully, but when I try to fit the data on it, I get :

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 6250000 values, but the requested shape has 400000000
     [[node reshape_1/Reshape (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1781) ]]
     [[node loss/mul (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:865) ]]
```

Here, my batch size is 50, so for a layer with (B,H,W,C) inputs of (50,50,50,50), the size should be 6250000, butt for (50,50,50,3200), it should be 400000000, which means that the output of cross correlation layer is 50 channels.

I am either interpreting this wrong or I have made a mistake somewhere which I would like to know about.

I am using keras 2.1.2 with tensorflow 1.13.1 (That was the version in which the custom layer was written and I was getting other problems with latest version)

I am also using a custom generator if that is needed info and calling fit using `md.fit_generator(train_gen,verbose=1)`. I can also add any other detail necessary.